# Parsing out login information with Python

Tags: python, parsing, extract

I am trying to find a way to parse out certain information with python. Here is the input I will need to parse/extract:

> Successful Network Logon:
>
> ```
>     User Name:      chango
>
>     Domain:         world
>
>     Logon ID:               (0x0,0x4BBE4382)
>
>     Logon Type:     3
>
>     Logon Process:  NtLmSsp
>
>     Authentication Package: NTLM
>
>     Workstation Name:       computer
>
>     Logon GUID:     -
> ```

I need to extract certain data from that input. Particularly the username, domain, login_ID, login type, login process, authentication package, and workstation name.

Essentially I need each of those values into a separate variable. I am having difficulty figuring out how to parse this and extract what I need.

Please help me.

Code:

```
def parse_xml(file):
    File_Read = open(file, "rb")
    mess =[]
    try:   

        tree = parse(File_Read)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for EventItem in root.findall("EventLogItem"):
            try:
                if "540" in EventItem.find("EID").text:

                    date = EventItem.find("genTime").text

                    message = EventItem.find("message").text

                    destination = re.findall(r'Target Server Name:\t(.+)\r', message)
                    #destination = re.findall(r'(Target Server Name:)', message)
                    #s = re.split(r'\n\t', message)
                    mess.append(s)
            except: pass    

    except: pass
    return mess
```

Comment: How do I paste code in here? is it [code] [/code]?

Comment: No \`code\` the ~ key without shift

Comment: There is a format button in the editor of your question. Select the code and hit the braces to perform the 4 space indents. Dont put it in the comments. No one can read this

Comment: as you can see in my code, I am parsing an xml file that contains event logs. It is looking for a particular EID and declaring variables based on certain xml tags.
One of those tags is "message" which is the part I posted above. I need to take parts of that message out and put them into separate variables as I mentioned above.

Comment: I tried to split the message with the '\n\t', but that didn't look right at all.

Comment: `except: pass`. How do you expect to ever debug your code when you are intentionally ignoring all errors?

Comment: This is just for testing ways to extracts parts of the "message". I am not trying to debug this testing code.

Comment: I don't even see any values matching up between the source input and what you are parsing in the code.

Comment: What is your exact source? The sample you have pasted is not XML.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a single correlation between your sample code and your sample input, but if all you are trying to do is parse that text into key/value pairs, then you can probably do simple splits. This assumes your key is always separated by a `:`

```py
raw = """
    User Name:      chango
    Domain:         world
    Logon ID:               (0x0,0x4BBE4382)
    Logon Type:     3
    Logon Process:  NtLmSsp
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Workstation Name:       computer
    Logon GUID:     -
"""

parsed = dict(map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1)) for line in raw.split('\n') if line.strip())

print parsed

{'Authentication Package': 'NTLM',
 'Domain': 'world',
 'Logon GUID': '-',
 'Logon ID': '(0x0,0x4BBE4382)',
 'Logon Process': 'NtLmSsp',
 'Logon Type': '3',
 'User Name': 'chango',
 'Workstation Name': 'computer'}

print parsed['User Name']
# chango

username = parsed['User Name']
print username
# chango
```

Comment: There is no correlation because there is a separate main function that takes in an xml file and then calls this function to parse it. Therefore, the "message" variable which looks exactly like your raw variable is populated from the contents of the xml file.

Comment: I appreciate your input on this jdi. It is close to what I am looking for, but I need each item into a separate variable. Perhaps I can split on ":"? Then I will get the "'" single quote in my string which I do not want. 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Example is:
username = chango
domain = world
etc.
I need the values declared into separate variables.

Comment: But you have a dict right there with all of your mappings. Its done.